# I'm having trouble with an animation I want to do with JS and CSS in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm a beginner to website building, and I wanted to create an animation every time a button is pressed. So I tried doing it on CSS first, but realized it could not be done with that alone, so I incorporated JS into my code which is still not working. The idea is, when I press the button, "Filter", the menu that is in the element, ".filter" comes down, so I tried adding an animation to shift the margin down, which does not work. How can I make this work?

```js
function btnFilter() {
  document.getElementByClass(".filter").style.WebkitAnimation = "filter-animation";
  document.getElementByClass(".filter").style.animation = "filter-animation";
}
```

```css
.filter {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
  border-left: 1px solid #ffffff;
  border-right: 1px solid #ffffff;
  margin-top: -57px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes filter-animation {
  from {
    margin-top: -57px;
    display: none;
  }
  to {
    margin-top: 30px;
    display: flex;
  }
}
@keyframes filter-animation {
  from {
    margin-top: -57px;
    display: none;
  }
  to {
    margin-top: 30px;
    display: flex;
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="btnFilter()">Filter</button>
<div class="filter">
  <p>filter</p>
  <form class="drpdwn-1">
    <p>Price range:</p>
    <select value="Price Range">
      <option>$0 - $50</option>
      <option>$50 - $100</option>
      <option>> $100</option>
    </select>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Note it should be `getElementsByClassName()`, not `getElementByClass()`, and that also returns an array of elements so you need to loop through the array and update the `style` on each individually. It would also be much easier to apply a class to the element and put the keyframe animation on that class.

Answer (score 0):

```
function btnFilter() {
  document.getElementsByClassName(".filter").style.WebkitAnimation = "filter-animation";
  document.getElementsByClassName(".filter").style.animation = "filter-animation";
}
```

use `getElementsByClassName('.className')...`

Comment: Actually it's `getElementsByClassName()` and avoid the `.` in the parameters. So your code is invalid.
Please avoid rushing to respond and test your code first.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery(JS)may help you
https://jsfiddle.net/moongod101/h8t6347b/ 
My way to do it is just use the jQuery function `addClass`,easy and simple

Answer (score 0):

You can use just CSS but you need to toggle a css class for animating the button every time.

Here is an example:

```js
var el = document.querySelector(".button");

el.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if(!el.classList.contains("animate")) {
    el.classList.add("animate"); 
  } else {
    el.classList.remove("animate"); 
  }
});
```

```css
.button {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: white;
  background-color: #777;
  padding: 0.7em 2em;
  border: 0;
  margin: 1em auto 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #444;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  appearance: none;
  
  transition: transform 1.5s ease;
}

.animate {
  transform: translateY(50px);
}
```

```html
<button class="button">Click me</button>
```